# Is there any library can edit the existing footer in a pdf file?

Tags: pdf, edit

I'm trying to modify the footer in a pdf file.

The footer is something like:

- Left side: some text.
- Center: page number.
- Right side: empty.

And actually I want to edit the left side. Is there any library can do that?

Comment: Are all the PDF files that you want to process essentially the same (from same source)? If so, can you post an example? Otherwise, you are looking for a general solution that would handle any PDF file?

Comment: It's basically in the same format: the left side is name of a form like "Form1 - Abc", the center is the page number, it's like "1 / 3".

Comment: "It's basically in the same format" do you have an example PDF you can post?

Comment: What kind of licensing are you looking for? Are you looking for unpaid/free solution?